# Jasperreport encoding PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I having a problem with Jasper Report 4.1.1 Maven plug-in in Struts 2.

I export a Vietnamese report RTF format is ok, but when that report in PDF format font error I can not display Vietnamese.

I tried many different ways to add file font.jar `jasperreport.property` classpath or use the simplest way is to add a XML tag: `encoding = UTF-8` but it does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `isPdfEmbedded` and `pdfEncoding` properties for `font` element in your report template.
Don't forget that the font you are using must have Vietnamese support.

The sample:

```
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="49" y="0" width="359" height="38"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Please check that your report has also correct encoding:

```
<property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: <action name="thongKeLoaiKhieuTo" class="com.gosol.webapp.action.ThongKeLoaiKhieuToAction" method="reportExample">
 <result name="success" type="jasper">
  <param name="location">/jasper/loaiKhieuTo.jasper</param>
  <param name="dataSource">beanCollection</param>   
  <param name="format">PDF</param>
 </result>
 <result name="error" type="jasper">/error.jsp</result>
</action>

Comment: Do you have report template source (with jrxml extension) file?